# Will a DC offset drift create any noise?

Tags: noise

Transducers have a certain DC offset and it can drift relatively quickly. After a high-pass filter is used (say 0.1 Hz) will there be any noise in the frequency bands of interest (eg. 30Hz-200Hz) because of this drift? How to estimate the amplitude or voltage density of this noise? This is in the context of online processing.

Answer (score 3):

> it can drift relatively quickly.

That's the key factor here. "Drifting DC offset" is essentially  the same thing as "lots of very low frequency energy". The speed of the drift will determine the affected frequency range.

You should probably do a spectral analysis of some typical drift signals (without any DC blocking) and see how far up the drift extends in frequency. Hopefully there is a nice low minimum between the drift and the frequency range of interests. That's where you should put the high pass filter.

Comment: Thanks. It would take me some time to do a spectral analysis. Is it possible to get some estimates for the noise density and the frequency range before that to see if I am on the right track? I have some estimates about the drift rates. In one configuration it is 25 uV per hour. Any way to estimate noise density and the noise frequency range from this?

Comment: How big is the signal of interest compared to your 25 uV?  Also how low in frequency is the signal of interest?  Evidently, the DC value is of no interest, right?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Starting range is about 50uV. I would like to make the calculations from assuming the frequency of interest starts at 10 Hz. The DC signal is of no interest.

Comment: Hilmar, given the limitations of thermal white or pink noise created at the electrode skin interface, with a corner frequency between 10-100Hz, it is not possible to separate the noise created by DC drift. Apparently, even the DC offset depends on the gel and skin condition. Do you have any idea about the expected range of noise created by DC drift post high-pass filter in real time processing?

Comment: Sorry, this depends on too many specifics, so the only way to answer this question you will have to do spectral analysis of the actual data from your actual setup. Power Spectral Density estimation is one of the most fundamental methods of signal processing and there a lots of tools and libraries availability: what's your concern about doing it?